# Why is HTML5 audio getting stalled in Safari?

Tags: html, audio, safari, html5-audio

I am observing a strange behavior of HTML5 audio in Safari 7.0.6 under Mac OS 10.9.4.

I create an audio element like this

```
<audio id="audio" controls preload="none" src="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples/4353.mp3">
```

Then I try to play it with via JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready
(

  function()
  {

    console.log('Document ready');

    $('audio').bind
    (
      'stalled',
      function()
      {
        console.log('Stalled');
        this.load();
      }
    );

    $('audio').bind
    (
      'canplaythrough',
      function()
      {
        console.log('Can play through');
        this.play();
        console.log('Play');
      }
    );

    console.log('Begin load');

    // It will begin to load even if you comment the following line out
    $('audio').trigger('load');

  }

);
```

I am experiencing a couple of problems with this script in Safari only.

1. For an unknown reason the audio begins to load even if I did not invoke the `load` method and even if I specify the `preload="none"` attribute. How can I force the Safari not to load the audio before I request it?
2. When the loading starts the audio gets stalled a couple of times. Why does it stall? How can I fix it? This does not happen in any other browser. This causes an audio to load 4-5 times which results in a large delay before it can be played.

Thank you for help!

P.S. here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lagufeqamadi/23) illustrating the problem.

Comment: Apple forum discussion on the issue (also no replies): https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6838273